# How to grab only distinct values in mongoDB and meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, chat, meteor

So lets say my chatsDB is filled with this data:

```
{_id: "39e92f36-5d0f-44b7-8948-89be9b85bd08", fromPerson: "John Smith", toPerson: "Bob Smith", message: "Hey Buddy"}
{_id: "39e92f36-5d0f-44b7-8948-89be9b85bd08", fromPerson: "John Smith", toPerson: "Joe Smith", message: "Hi how you doing"}
{_id: "39e92f36-5d0f-44b7-8948-89be9b85bd08", fromPerson: "Tom Smith", toPerson: "Bob Smith", message: "Hello Again!"}
{_id: "39e92f36-5d0f-44b7-8948-89be9b85bd08", fromPerson: "Bob Smith", toPerson: "John Smith", message: "Hello Again!"}
```

I want to return a unique set of results from querying this mongoDB. How do I do this?

For example in SQL+php:

`Select fromPerson Distinct from chatsDB;`

My thought right now is to render the template with a list of from and to people to get a "chatUserList" of the people a user has spoken with.

Answer (score 9):

MongoDB has a [distinct()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) command which does exactly what you're after in this case.

Example finding distinct senders for all chats:

```
> db.chatsDB.distinct('fromPerson');
[ "John Smith", "Tom Smith", "Bob Smith" ]
```

Example using a query filter to find unique people sending messages to 'John Smith':

```
> db.chatsDB.distinct('fromPerson', { toPerson: 'John Smith'});
[ "Bob Smith" ]
```

If this is going to be a common query type for your application, you should add appropriate indexes .. for example, on `fromPerson` or `(fromPerson, toPerson)`.

Comment: but I am using meteor and the collections with meteor, to my understanding don't allow you to do db.chatsDB. anything...
For example I have: 

Messages = new Meteor.Collection('messages');
then I would call Messages.find();

Comment: I have the same problem trying to run a distinct on Meteor. Javascript console says <collection>.distinct is not a function. So i guess it's not supported in Meteor?

Comment: Turns out that Meteor does not yet have helpers for MongoDB's `distinct()` or `aggregate()` features :(.  A more relevant answer with a `distinct` function prototype is: [StackOverflow: mongodb distinct() implementation in Meteor on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901761).  This is based off a [pull request for aggregate()](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644) that appears to have been closed but not merged.

Comment: The solution makes not mention of Meteor.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the mongodb documentation at [this page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation). It describes how to create a distinct query.