# mongodb distinct() implementation in Meteor on the server?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to fetch distinct values from the mongodb in Meteor (basically, implementing mongodb native distinct() call). On client side, [Does Meteor have a distinct query for collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514733/does-meteor-have-a-distinct-query-for-collections) - this works like a charm. But I can't figure out how to get something similar to work on the server side. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514733/does-meteor-have-a-distinct-query-for-collections

Comment: It's not, at least not entirely, I linked to that one. It only works on the client apparently.

Answer (score 3):

Ok after some digging around the code and realizing mongo lib contains native implementations of all the needed methods I reused the aggregate() solution from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644

Straightforward changes and translation to coffeescript gives the following snippet to put into your server side code:

```
path = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("path")
MongoDB = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("mongodb")
Future = __meteor_bootstrap__.require(path.join("fibers", "future"))

myCollection = new Meteor.Collection "my_collection"

#hacky distinct() definition from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644
myCollection.distinct = (key)->
  future = new Future
  @find()._mongo.db.createCollection(@_name,(err,collection)=>
    future.throw err if err
    collection.distinct(key, (err,result)=>
      future.throw(err) if err
      future.ret([true,result])
      )
    )
  result = future.wait()
  throw result[1] if !result[0]
  result[1]
```

Downside is you have to define it for every new collection but that's pretty straightforward to fix with another hack via _.extend or something I guess...

PS It's also now a smart package - `mrt add mongodb-aggregation`

Comment: I'm using meteor 0.8.2 and had to make the following substitutions to use this code __meteor_bootstrap__ => Npm,  future.ret => future.return. Requiring mongodb appears to be unnecessary. I would have used the package, however it lacks support for user authentication making the underlying collection completely open.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is trying this in Meteor v1.0+ (1.0.2), this code worked for me, I put it on the server. Basically the same as J Ho's answer with the tweaks mentioned - Npm.require, as well as the Future['return']. Cleaned up just a little for the Coffeescripters out there.

I was considering the package, but already had `meteorhacks:aggregate` package (only `aggregate` function), thus didn't want to chance overwriting it with another package. So, I just rolled my own `distinct` from the help of everyone else.

Hope this helps someone! Most likely, if I continue to use distinct on more collections, I'll use `_.extend Meteor.Collection` like here: `https://github.com/zvictor/meteor-mongo-server/blob/master/server.coffee`

```
path = Npm.require('path')
Future = Npm.require(path.join('fibers', 'future'))

myCollection = new Meteor.Collection "my_collection"

myCollection.distinct = (key, query) ->
  future = new Future
  @find()._mongo.db.createCollection @_name, (err,collection) =>
    future.throw err if err

    collection.distinct key, query, (err,result) =>
      future.throw(err) if err
      future['return']([true,result]) 

  result = future.wait()
  throw result[1] if !result[0]
  result[1]
```